# ASP.NET MVC SubString help

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC app that shows news articles and for the main paragraph I have a truncate and HTML tag stripper. e.g. `<p><%= item.story.RemoveHTMLTags().Truncate() %></p>`

The two functions are from an extension and are as follows:

```
public static string RemoveHTMLTags(this string text)
{
    return Regex.Replace(text, @"<(.|\n)*?>", string.Empty);
}
public static string Truncate(this string text)
{
    return text.Substring(0, 200) + "...";
}
```

However when I create a new article say with a story with only 3-4 words it will throw this error: `Index and length must refer to a location within the string.
Parameter name: length`

What is the problem? Thanks

Comment: out of 164 views I can't be the only person to have found this topic useful and as such upvoted it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change your truncate function to this:

```
public static string Truncate(this string text) 
{     
    if(text.Length > 200)
    {
        return text.Substring(0, 200) + "..."; 
    }
    else
    {
        return text;
    }

}
```

A much more useful version would be

```
public static string Truncate(this string text, int length) 
{     
    if(text.Length > length)
    {
        return text.Substring(0, length) + "..."; 
    }
    else
    {
        return text;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your length parameter is longer than the string, so it's [throwing an exception just as the function documentation states](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx).

In other words, if the string isn't 200 characters long, `Substring(0, 200)` doesn't work.

You need to dynamically determine the substring based on the original string's length.  Try:

```
return text.Substring(0, (text.Length > 200) : 200 ? text.Length);
```

Comment: Okies how can I fix it? Basically want it is supposed to do is truncate stories over 200 characters long. If they are less than 200 then it shouldn't truncate it.