# How can I truncate a string using MVC Html Helpers?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to truncate a long string for display only on my index page.  It is shown like so:

```
<td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
</td>
```

The Description can be 500 characters long but I can't show that much on that grid layout.  I'd like to show just the first 25 as they can see all of it on the Details page but I cannot seem to get it to work with out truncating it at the model level.

Something like this would be nice:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description.Take(25))
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description.Substring(0,25)
```

EDIT

I'm getting the following exception at Runtime when I try either method.

```
Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.
```

Comment: Have you considered creating an additional model property that performs the substring and using that?

Comment: Yeah, that was how I was going to do it if there wasn't a way to work with the Templates and single property.

Comment: Your specific problem here is that the expression passed into `Html.DisplayFor` must reference an actual property, not a specific value. In other words, you can only do `@Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Description)`, not `@Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Description.Substring(0, 25))`. You don't need to use `Html.DisplayFor` for this, though, so you can just write `@item.Description.Substring(0, 25)`. However, bear in mind @48klocs's comment to Nathan A's answer.

Comment: Note that `Take()` returns a `IEnumerable<char>`, not a string.  `Substring()` is more suited for this.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Don't use the html helper.  Just do this:

```
@item.Description.Substring(0, Math.Min(item.Description.Length, 25));
```

I'm assuming you are in some loop where `item` is the current element.

Comment: That will throw an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` if the string isn't longer than 25 characters.

Comment: @NathanA , this works great, but can you provide option 2 to show dots at the end like this `mydescription .....` , i tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4610199/asp-net-mvc-substring-help) and gives error when parsed, do you have any idea?

Comment: @NathanA thank you so much. I was struggling with this since 2 hours finally got the solution

Answer (score 7):

You could do this with an extension method.

```
public static string Truncate(this string source, int length)
{
    if (source.Length > length)
    {
        source = source.Substring(0, length);
    }

    return source;
}
```

Then in your view:

```
@item.Description.Truncate(25)
```

Comment: That still won't work.  DisplayFor only accepts expressions that result in a value (specifically what's listed in the error), not method calls.  That's what is generating the *Templates* error.

Comment: @NathanA you're probably right.  I didn't check what the call for `DisplayFor` vs. `Display` was.  I think a named `Display` element should work, but I'm just guessing there.

Comment: That looks better. Good general application.

Answer (score 4):

you could either truncate the data before it gets to the View, or use this Razor:

```
@{
    var shortDescript = String.Concat(modelItem.Take(25));
}
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => shortDescript)
```

Comment: While that may work, why would you use `DisplayFor` at all then? Any benefit you would get using it on a member of your data model is lost doing it this way.

Comment: Assuming the type did not change (string to string), you can still make use of the same display template. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/6365658/1445356

Answer (score 1):

You might consider creating a special model property for such instances where you need this:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string MyDescription {get; set;}
    public string MyShortDescription {
        get 
        {
              return Truncate(MyDescription, 25);
        }
}

private string Truncate(string, howMany)
{
   // Code to perform the substring here
}

@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MyShortDescription);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this **if you want to use the HTML helpers**. Say you want to get part of a string before the first space **.IndexOf(' ')** (or you can just use a predefined index 25 like u said):

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description).ToString().Substring(0,item.Description.IndexOf(' '))
```

Answer (score 1):

The HTML helper for ASP Net Core 3 MVC.

```
public static HtmlString Truncate(this IHtmlHelper helper, string text, int maxLength = 100)
{
    if (text == null) return new HtmlString("");

    if (text.Length > maxLength)
    {
        text = text.Substring(0, maxLength) + "...";
    }
    return new HtmlString($"{text}");
}
```

Use in cshtml file

```
@Html.Truncate(item.Description)
```

Or you can use param

```
@Html.Truncate(item.MusicUrl, 50)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try an extension

```
public static string TruncateMiddle(this string value, int lengthExpected, string separator = "...")
    {
        if (value.Length <= lengthExpected) return value;

        decimal sepLen = separator.Length;
        decimal charsToShow = lengthExpected - sepLen;
        decimal frontChars = Math.Ceiling(charsToShow / 2);
        decimal backChars = Math.Floor(charsToShow / 2);

        return value.Substring(0, (int)frontChars) + separator + value.Substring(value.Length - (int)backChars);            
    }
```

Use

```
MyLongString.TruncateMiddle(50)
```

Return something like this: Lorem ipsum dolor sit ame...onsectetur cras amet.